# font weight varies between 2 pages but has exact same css and code

Tags: css

hey smarter than I am peeps :
comparing 2 URL's :
https://www.purelocal.com.au/
https://www.purelocal.com.au/palm-beach-pools-burleigh-heads

desktop > top right > the 2 search fields > their placeholders > 'keyword..' and 'city or postcode'
if you look closely you see they have different boldness , however they have the exact same CSS and HTML.
Can someone please let me know why these 2 placeholder fonts have different boldness-ess ??

Thanks to all !!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are different CSS rules for the two, where one has 25px font size set and the other has 25.5px set. Refer to the following images for details:

Larger font size CSS rule
[image: Larger font size CSS rule (image)]

---

Smaller font size CSS rule
[image: Smaller font size CSS rule (image)]

Answer (score 0):

One has:

```
font-family: 'Libre Franklin'!important;
font-size: 25px!important;
```

that is loaded from
https://ik.imagekit.io/mqpttb8ig/aa0+home+lato.css

The other has:

```
font-family: libre franklin!important;
font-size: 25.5px!important;
```

that is loaded from
https://ik.imagekit.io/mqpttb8ig/profile-roboto-nobg.css

Comment: I've checked the URl above (palm beach pools) and the font-size is : 25.5px
both homepage and listing page has 25.5px for the searchbox1 and searchbox2